# LVCMOS line matching

Tags: matching, lvcmos

I have this ADS6125 ADC it has internal registers which can be programmed. The programming interface is LVCMOS I am planning to programm the registers with a 10 kHz clock frequency. How tight does this lines have to be matched? Should I use terminations?

Comment: It all comes down to 1) what device are you going to use to drive the ADS6125 and 2) what is the trace length between the driving device and the ADC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is to clear up some misconceptions I’ve seen in so far as when termination are needed on PCB traces, specifically when using LVCMOS interfaces.  Contrary to what some may say, just because thousands of designs are out there does not mean that they are good designs.

With any interface, the question as to whether or not to terminate comes down to 1) what is the edge rate of the signal; 2) what is the interconnect length and topology; and 3) what is the tolerance of the signal to ringing, undershoot, or overshoot.

The OP was asking about a clock interface.  These are the most critical from an SI standpoint.  For any clock interface, you want to eliminate any ringing where the ringing could cross or come close to the destination device’s switching threshold.  A small amount of overshoot or undershoot is probably tolerable, so long as that doesn’t turn on the ESD protection diodes.  For all of our designs, it is a requirement that a source termination resistor be provided for a clock signal even if it is not thought to be needed.  It’s far easier to make this resistor a small value if it’s not needed than to come back and rev the PCB.

Data interfaces are usually more tolerant of ringing, so long as the signal is stable at the receiver when it’s sampled.  But excessive ringing can cause the ESD protection diodes in the receiving device to conduct.  If the analysis doesn’t show that these ESD diodes can sustain the repeated current transients due to the over/undershoot, than you probably don’t have a robust design.

LVCMOS drivers run the gamut so far as edge speed and drive strength are concerned.  Here are some simulations I ran.  The schematic is shown below.  I then varied the driver speed/strength and interconnect length.  In all cases all the transmission line (trace) segments were constant with Zo=55 ohms.

[image]

The waveform below is using a medium speed driver (generic part, from the Hypeylynx provided library), under fast-strong drive conditions and with a trace length of 8.6 inches.

[image]

Note the large amount of ringing at the destination (light green trace) which is sure to cause clocking problems, in addition to perhaps overstressing the ESD diodes in the destination part.

The inclusion of a 49 ohm source termination resistor cleans up the ringing, as the simulation below shows.

[image]

Some might say that “I don’t have to worry about ringing or other SI issues because my interconnect length is short.”  Well, maybe.  Below is a simulation of that same interface with a trace length of 2.1 in and no source termination.  While the ringing may not cause double clocking, it surely will cause the receiver’s ESD diodes to conduct.

[image]

Using a slow-weak model for the driver cleans up the waveform as shown below.

[image]

But how do you guarantee slow-weak driver performance?  One way is the use of a source termination resistor!

Some of the issues I’ve raised fall into the long-term reliability bucket.  Take the issue of ESD diodes conducting.  How do you know; how can you guarantee that such repeated current surges through those diodes aren’t going to cause device degradation over time?  And what might be acceptable for a 2 or 3 year life consumer product is not going to pass muster for a critical space asset that has a 15 year life expectancy.

In short, you really need to model your interfaces, even when you don’t think you’re going to have a problem.  And be conservative.

Comment: So you are telling me that I should use a 50 Ohm termination resistor at the source of the signal? I thought terminating close to the receiver is how you do it.

Comment: @electrococuk - I'm saying you should make provisions for a source termination resistor.  The actual value can be determined later, but it will probably be in the range of 22 ohms to 51 ohms.  You need to model/simulate that interface, using the actual driving device, board stackup/trace paramaters (which establish Zo of the interconnect).

Comment: @electrococuk - And the reason you don't parallel terminate at the destination is that the driving device usually can't provide the current to drive a parallel termination resistor, which would be 40 - 50 ohms.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, if your trace lengths are less than 1/20 of the wavelength of your highest frequency signal, you don't need to worry about transmission line effects.

Lets say your 10 kHz data signals have important frequency content up to ~50 kHz. Then the relevant wavelength is 6 km, so if your trace lengths are less than 300 m, you don't need to worry about transmission line effects.

Practically, your CMOS drivers might produce "fast" edges with much more than 50 kHz frequency content. You can limit this effect by including a series resistor at each driver output. Anywhere from 5 to 500 ohms should work in an undemanding application like yours.

> Should I use terminations?

Typically CMOS drivers are not designed to drive a load with low enough resistance to usefully terminate a transmission line.

Comment: Technically that’s incorrect. CMOS can easily drive a 300 Ohm trace without reflections and ringing by suitable design, but generally the L is10 nH/cm and input C about 6pF per gate so the ringing damped by the 25  Ohm Logic +/-50% for 3.6V logic @ 3.3V.  Newbies tend to see false ringing with an excessively long ground clip and 20~30 pF 10:1 probe causing ringing at 30MHz or more.

Comment: It's the edge rates you have be concerned about, not just the data/clock rate.  And LVCMOS can, depending on the device generate fast edges on the order of a couple of ns.  So if you want to use The Photon's recommendation, put in the frequency equivalent of a (say) 5 ns edge, rather than your 10 KHz signal.  When you do this, make sure you account for the propagation time on your board, which is probably around 2 ns/foot (this is not in a vacuum).

Comment: And I agree about the use of series/back/source terminations.

Comment: @SteveSh, You're right that the edge rate is most important. But 1000's and 1000's of successful designs have been done with CMOS with no consideration for termination. Only for really long traces (maybe over 20 cm) or if you're using a really fast family (F or AC, for example)  should you have to worry about it.